# Flask on ec2 not receiving connections

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

I'm running a simple flask app on EC2.

When I request `GET "/"` from `localhost:5000`, it returns `{'hello': 'world'}`.

But when I request the public ip from outside the server, it doesn't return anything and eventually times out.

Heres the `launch-wizard-2`'s inbound rules:
[image]

When I `curl -v http://IP_ADDRESS:5000`, I get the response:

```
* Trying ADDRESS...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

Here is my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Update(Resource):
    def get(self):
        print('getting request')
        return {'hello': 'world'}

    def post(self):
        return {'hello': 'world world'}

api.add_resource(Update, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: What are the settings on the launch-wizard-2 security group?

Comment: Where would I find those settings?